# Как сделать элемент кликабельным внутри блока, но при этом чтобы сам блок не фиксировал клик?

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня в системе есть уведомления, при нажатии на блок уведомления происходит переход на страницу с чем это уведомление связано. Бывают случаи когда уведомление можно просто отметить как прочитанное.

код:

```
<div class="block-notifi">
<div class="title">текст уведомления</div>
<div class="delet">удалить</div>
</div>
```

блок `block-notifi` весь кликабельный, но бывает такое что уже просмотрел и надо просто убрать уведомление кликнув `delet`, но проблема в том, что весь блок `block-notifi` кликабельный из-за этого по клику на `delet` переходит на страницу, а должно просто убираться уведомление.

**Как сделать?**

Код js:

```
$('.notification-line').click(function(){

    // Получаем ID 
    id_notification = $(this).data("notification"); 
    id_lead_go = $(this).data("lead-id");   

    // другой код, который совершает переход на нужную страницу 

});
$('.delet-notifi').click(function(){

    // Получаем ID 
    id_notification = $(this).data("id-notification");  
    id_lead_go = $(this).data("lead-id");   

    // другой код, который убирает уведомление.                             
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У объект события (`Event`), который в вашем случае даже не используется, есть отличный метод `stopPropogation`
Метод отменяет всплытие, которое как раз и является корнем вашей проблемы.

Когда вы нажимаете на блок, вызывается `обработчик` **элемента**, на которых вы кликнули, после вызывается `обработчик` ( если есть ) **родительского элемента**, на чьего потомка вы кликнули и так далее до `document`, поэтому то и срабатывает обработчик `document.onclick`, даже если мы кликнем на `ul`, `a` т.д.

Вам надо чуть чуть изменить ваш код:

```
/* объект событие передается в обработчик первым параметром */
$('.delet-notifi').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); // убрали всплытие
    // Получаем ID 
    id_notification = $(this).data("id-notification");  
    id_lead_go = $(this).data("lead-id");   

    // другой код, который убирает уведомление.                             
});
```

[Для развития](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling)

Comment: не работает...          $('.notification-line').click(function(e){
 e.stopPropogation();
 // Получаем ID 
 id_notification = $(this).data("notification"); 
          id_lead_go = $(this).data("lead-id"); 
 //var f = 1;
 //sendnotifi(f);
 alert('клик');
          
          
         });
         $('.delet-notifi').click(function(){
          
          // Получаем ID 
          id_notification = $(this).data("id-notification"); 
          id_lead_go = $(this).data("lead-id"); 
          //var f = 2;
          //sendnotifi(f);
          alert('клик1');
         });

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev просто опечатка, наверное, `e.stopPropogation();` надо  `e.stopPropagation();` через `a`.

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev, исправил опечатку

Answer (score 1):

Вам просто нужно в обработчике события принимать объект события и останавливать его дальнейшее распространение (всплытие):

```
$('.delet-notifi').click(function(e){

    // Ваш код
    e.stopPropagation(); // чтобы событие не всплывало дальше (на уровень выше)                            
});
```

В IE версии 8 и ниже надо использовать свойство события `cancelBubble`, то есть так `e.cancelBubble = true;`

Также существует метод `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` - он действует подобно `e.stopPropagation();`, но при этом еще и предотвращает вызов всех остальных обработчиков на текущем объекте (если они есть).